# Runtime.getRuntime().exec gets no results when used from java netbeans

Tags: java, r, cmd, netbeans-8

I am working on a Java project, and stuck at a step as it is showing no results.

The java code is:

```
public class callPgs {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try{    
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/R/R-3.2.0/bin/Rscript.exe C:/R/R-3.2.0/bin/arrayqualityMetrics.R");

        int processComplete = p.waitFor();

                   if (processComplete == 0) {

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Process is completed");
                        System.out.println("successfull");
                   } else {
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You Have selected Wrong Input File");
                        System.out.println("Could not complete");
                   }
                }
                catch (Exception e1)
                {
                               e1.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
```

}

as I am executing this by using command prompt using Rscript.exe

`C:\R\...\bin\Rscript "arrayqualityMetrics.R"`

I am getting my results correctly
but when I am doing it by Java netbeans using the above code, it is showing else option as "Could not complete" in the netbean's console.

As other RScripts are running good and without any error but this one is not giving the results, as the Rscript is for arrayqualityMetrics as:-

library(arrayQualityMetrics)

library(limma)

library(tcltk)

options( warn = -1 ) #commands for removing warnings as they are comming when running the Rscript from the R console.

X <-tk_choose.files(caption = "Choose Files")

maData<-read.maimages(X, source="agilent", other.columns = "gProcessedSignal", green.only=TRUE)

eSet<-new("ExpressionSet", exprs = maData$other$gProcessedSignal, annotation =maData$genes[,7])

arrayQualityMetrics(eSet, outdir="QC_C", force = TRUE, do.logtransform = TRUE)

So I want to ask weather there is any error in the Rscript or there is any thing I should add in the java code to run it properly....
Any help is appreciable......

Comment: Does it print stacktrace?

Comment: Why is there a "javascript" tag on this question?  Can someone with Javascript expertise answer this question?  Doesn't seem so to me.

Comment: Try `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\R\\R-3.2.0\\bin\\Rscript.exe my_script.R");`

Comment: @ user3735633
no it is not printing any thing

Comment: Thanks... everyone for the reply.......
I have done it but still it is not working, I don't know why @ user3145373 ツ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do :

```
try{    
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\R\\R-3.2.0\\bin\\Rscript.exe C:\\dir\my_script.R");

        int processComplete = p.waitFor();

           if (processComplete == 0) {
                System.out.println("successfull");
           } else {
                System.out.println("Could not complete");
           }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

try to add full path to your file that need to be executed.
I have tried with this simple example and that works fine for me.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad C:\\abc.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks..... user3145373 ツ.....
but still it is not giving any results and the console is giving "Could not complete" message......

Comment: So there is still some problem while getting `RScript.exe`. If possible then pass file as second argument.

Comment: Hey, try to add full path of your `my_script.R` file.

Comment: Hey.. I have tried all ways to execute this, but I still don't know where am I getting wrong.I have edited the Java code just now in my question.  now it is giving "sucessful" message in the console but still now giving my output file which  should come when the script is executed @ - user3145373 ツ

Comment: @Aaryan : Have you tried it by removing `.exe` extension from path of Rscript ? If no, try by removing the extension.

Comment: yes sir/mam, I have tried every way to get results.But not getting the output file.... Not getting results....... :( @user3145373 ツ

Comment: @Aaryan: ok, let me check.

Comment: Thank you sir, for your deep concer to the problem. It is solved.
@user3145373 ツ

Comment: Actually sir it was the path problem.... I think............,  because when I changed the path (hit and trail method) ..... and it worked fine.... thank you sir  C:/R/R-3.2.0/bin/Rscript C:/dir/my_script.R @ user3145373 ツ

Comment: If you got proper solution then you can accept any one answer that helps you to solve your issue. So people will not came to see the solved question. :)

Comment: Yes using the absolute path is a must :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you connect to the processes inputstream then you will not be able to capture it.

See

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()

as in

```
 InputStream os = p.getInputStream ();
 while ((b = os.read ()) != -1) {
    System.out.print (b);
 }
```

Comment: can you be more specific with your answer...Plz...I am not getting it correctly....some details are required......

Comment: I am so much confused....still,..... I have edited the question that is giving the "sucessful" in the console can you help me out from here... it should generate a output file.
as my_script.R has command in it to generate a output file and it is giving results when run through command prompt but not through java eclipse software in windows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`waitFor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) the `Process` to finish. Per that Javadoc, that *causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this `Process` object has terminated.* Also, you'll probably want to add a catch for the possible `InterruptedException`. So, something like

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "C:/R/R-3.2.0/bin/Rscript.exe my_script.R");
    p.waitFor();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```